# Past audits on deleted posts fail to render due to JS error

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits, javascript

I recently stumbled onto an old post which mentioned the following failed audit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574594/) (deleted):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19920226

This is what's rendered:

> [image]

<sup>(The username has been redacted, as it contains some moderator-only information next to it - it *does* actually render correctly).</sup>

Note the distinct lack of the content being reviewed. In addition, there's an error in the console:

> full.en.js?v=e2f375bee881:6 Error connecting controller
>
> "element with popover id not found"
>
> {identifier: "s-popover", controller: t, element: input.s-input.s-input__search.js-search-field.blr0.h100.js-search-autocomplete}

This *appears* to be caused by the question being deleted *and* the review being an audit, as [this real review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3281) renders fine.

---

<sup>Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)</sup>

Comment: A simpler way to produce a screenshot would be to take it while logged out.